# ¿Podran darme una mano con esto?

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que resolver este ejercicio, pero recien estoy empezando con SQL.

Hice lo siguiente:

1)SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM Products

2)SELECT Orders.order_id, Products.product_id, Products.product_name, Order_Items.quantity
FROM Orders, Products, Order_Items

3)INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES customer_name
FROM Customers

Comment: En el punto 3, creo que lo que te pides es hacer la misma consulta de 2, pero que además incluya el nombre del cliente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para la solución de la segunda cuestión deberías hacer algo así.

```
SELECT order_id, product_id, product_name, quantity
FROM Orders O INNER JOIN Order_Items OI ON O.order_id=OI.order_id
INNER JOIN Products P ON OI.product_id=P.product_id
```

y para la tercera:

```
SELECT order_id, product_id, product_name, quantity, C.customer_name
FROM Products P INNER JOIN Order_Items OI ON P.product_id=OI.product_id
INNER JOIN Orders O ON OI.order_id=O.order_id
INNER JOIN Customers C ON O.customer_id=C.customer_id
```

Espero que te ayude

Comment: Justo ayer estaba leyendo sobre los INNER JOIN, eso es lo que me hacia falta. Muchas gracias!